# how to actually prompt user input in command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[50] = {0};
    scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);
    FILE *fp;
    char *filename;
    char ch;

    filename = str;
    printf("Filename : %s\n", filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");

    if ( fp )
    {
        printf("File contents:\n");
        while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
        {
            printf("%c",ch);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I've written this code which is supposed to ask user for their input, but when I run it, it shows nothing on command line arguments, when I press any key, it will display info like this:

> a
>   Filename :
>   Failed to open the file
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time : 1.078
>   Press any key to continue.

What have I done wrong??

Comment: `scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);` --> `printf("Enter file name:"); fflush(stdout); scanf("%49s", str);`

Comment: `scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);` is all wrong. Use `printf()` (or `puts()`) to print to the console. Output is line buffered, so nothing will be printed until you include a newline character (`\n`) or call `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: `scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);` doesn't print a message and then wait for input like you're expecting.  It prints nothing, but *requires the user to type* "Enter file name:" before the filename.  Run your program and instead of just pressing Enter, type "Enter file name:example.txt" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Never use `scanf` without checking its return value. If whoever is teaching you didn't tell you that, ask for your money back and find a better teacher.